# Is there a way to integrate CommonJ WorkManager with Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, commonj

Is there a way to integrate CommonJ WorkManager with Glassfish

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this myself but according to Sahoo (in [this thread](http://markmail.org/message/rlml6glywy2ks4n2)), the way to go would be to write a JCA connector and to use the [`javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager`](http://javadoc.glassfish.org/v3/apidoc/javax/resource/spi/work/WorkManager.html) API (which is part of JCA 1.5)

#### Resources

- [Parallel processing in Glassfish with Work Managers](http://markmail.org/message/jabry7tlkvwp4k2n)
- [JSR 322 - JavaEE Connector Architecture 1.6 - Reference Implementation - Half Pager](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=GFV3JSR322HalfPager)
- [`javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager`](http://javadoc.glassfish.org/v3/apidoc/javax/resource/spi/work/WorkManager.html) API

Answer (score 0):

A stackoverflow user has a solution posted elsewhere on StackOverflow:
[Using a CommonJ implementation with GlassFish and Spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490297/using-a-commonj-implementation-with-glassfish-and-spring-3)